# Browserify with node-webkit (nw.js) usage

Tags: gruntjs, browserify, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm using grunt-browserify to build my application for nw.js.
The problem is that process.cwd() or __dirname returns relative paths not absolute.
I've tried different combinations of detectGlobals and insertGlobals options. Doesnt work.
How do I restrict using browserify polyfills?

Answer (score 1):

Browserify Injects its own version of core node modules like `http`, `path`, `fs` and `process` to shim these inside browser environment, which will unfortunately over-ride the original ones in Node-Webkit. In order to fix that you need to fix browserify using `no-builtins` flag.

For grunt it should be

`{
 'no-builtins': true
}`

In browserify options in your gruntfile.